# Task Scheduler 1.0 - how to run a remote program from the command line

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-access, windows-vista, taskscheduler

How can I schedule a remote `program.exe`, which exists in computer A to run in computer B via `Task Scheduler 1.0` in Windows XP / Visa via the command line?

Note: psexec is not allowed

Comment: I'm not sure if you can manipulate the scheduled tasks on computer A from computer B but you could have a scheduled task on computer B that uses MS's SysInternals PsExec() program to run a program remotely on computer A. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec